# ZHS16GBK to UTF-8 converting issue

Tags: postgresql, oracle, goldengate

I've got an unusual issue. I am using oracle goldengate to migrate oracle database of ZHS16GBK charset to postgresql of UTF-8 charset. After working out a few issues, I encountered a charset issue that the Chinese characters (both in data and column comments) display normally when I use psql to connect to the postgres and query the pg_attribute view. But when I use client soft (navicat and dbeaver), the comments on tables display like `Ê×´Î»ØÓ¦Ê±¼ä`.

Is there anything wrong with my client configuration?
I've tried a few ways such as changing the connection in navicat or dbeaver of charset to utf-8,GBK, but it does not work.

Why does it display normally in psql connection?

I found a clue that when my Windows cmd line shows chcp is 936, it displays normally. When I change the chcp to 65501(UTF-8), the psql displays incorrectly just like the characters in the client soft window!

Comment: What do you mean by "migrate oracle database of ZHS16GBK charset to postgresql of UTF-8 charset"? Do you have an Oracle database or a PostgreSQL?